# Child's graphic novel series about a group of explorers looking for indigenous life

Tags: story-identification

This was a graphic novel series that I read around 2007-8.

There were two serials, one about some version of space basketball (in a purple cover) and one about people exploring planets (in a green cover).

They were short, and I found them near the Harry Potter books and novelisations of Series 1 of Pokemon at my school library.

Comment: Just to be clear, were the explorers also the people playing basketball?